ASP Net identity two factor authentication last expired token is getting validated successfully
I am using ASP Net identity with two factor authentication for user login.
I am generating two factor OTP like this
var token = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider);

I am sending this OTP to the user via email and then letting user login using this the OTP, this is the code I am using to validate the two factor authentication using token
var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();

var signIn = await _signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync(TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider, code, false, false);

if (signIn.Succeeded)
{
   // further code
}

The default timeout of the OTP is 3 minutes and I know this is not OPT but TOTP so if I try to generate token within the 3 minutes time period I get the same OTP as the previous one.
Which is fine for me.
The problem is that even after 3 minutes are passed and so the new OTP is generated, when I try the last OTP (which is supposed to be expired and that is why the new OTP is generated) also works and allows user to sign in.
This behavior is totally wrong, once the new OTP is generated, the old ones should never work.
Could anybody guide me if I am doing something wrong in my code or is there a way to correct this behavior?


Difference Between TOTP and OTP
OTP and TOTP are two types of security mechanisms that usually perform
the same function: verifying a user's identity for authentication.
One-Time Password (OTP) - OTP is a static password that becomes
invalid after being used once. Unlike your registered password, it
won’t be valid multiple times.
Time-Based One-Time Password (TOTP) - TOTP is a time-based OTP that
requires the user to enter the OTP within a given time. This window of
opportunity for entering the code in TOTP is usually 30 to 60 seconds.
After that, the TOTP expires and you must be issued a new one.
OTP vs TOTP Key Difference - TOTPs and OTPs differ in how long their
generated codes last, i.e., their validity. Most traditional OPTs are
counter-based, i.e., each login session requires a new OTP to be
generated.
TOTPs are time-based, i.e., the OTPs remain valid for a specified
timeframe – usually 30 to 60 seconds, after which it expires and a new
TOTP must be generated if you fail to enter the TOTP within that time.

https://instasafe.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-otp-and-totp/
So an OTP will expire on first use, regardless of when that happens, whereas TOTP may expire in time. So if you want to have a timeout on your token, you will need to use TOTP instead of OTP. Are you sure you want to invalidate your token after 3 minutes if it is being sent via email? What if the person is not quick-enough to validate?
Nevertheless, if you want timeouts to happen if the token is not being used up in time, you will need to switch to using TOTP rather than OTP.
After subsequent discussion with the asker and subsequent research, we found out that the actual issue was the 9-minute window as per https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27088
So, the exact issue seems to be detected and the asker is exploring possible solutions to it.

But the new TOTP is generated only when the old one is expired (after 3 minutes), at least that is what my logical understanding say and this is how it should work. So once the new TOTP is generated it should not let user login with the last expired TOTP, no?

@PawanNogariya if you generate a token and wait for 10 minutes, will it still be valid?https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27088 "By default, .NET uses the Rfc6238AuthenticationService class for generating and validating TOTP (Time-Based One-Time Password) codes. The issue with this class is that the generated TOTP code remains valid for 9 minutes, a timeframe hardcoded and unchangeable"

Just checked and yes it is exactly the same 9 minutes window when the previous OTP remains valid and becomes invalid post 9 minutes. But Thank you very much for pointing out the link to the issue. People have provided solutions also for this. I will try to implement one of the solutions.

@PawanNogariya of course, I'm happy to help. Let me know if one of those solutions works for you and of course, if this answer pointed you to the right direction, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Yes, one solution from this link https://github.com/AsifulNobel/AspNetCoreIssue27088 worked, I had to upgrade my project from .net 6 to .net 8 after that it worked. But then I found out even simpler solution to call _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user) method every time before generating the new token, and bang! everything is solved with this because whenever a new token is generated, all the older ones become invalidated because we reset the security stamp which solved all the problems

@PawanNogariya very good, I'm glad it ended up well for you.
